# How to give a header to the first side left column of the data frame using R?

Tags: r, header, dataframe

This may be like a very small question, but I need some help here.

Lets say I have a data frame (df) in **R** which reads like this:

```
    X   Y   Z
Ras 56  89  76
Jyo 76  90  00
Abi 45  88  34
Poo 78  98  54
```

I wish to give a header to the first column and name it as "Names", so as to get the following output.

```
Names   X   Y   Z
Ras 56  89  76
Jyo 76  90  00
Abi 45  88  34
Poo 78  98  54
```

When I check, it gives me the following headers:

```
> names(df)[1]
X
> names(df)[2]
Y
> names(df)[3]
Z
```

So I tried something like,

```
> names(df)[0] <- "Names"
```

But that did not do anything. Can anyone help me how do I give this "Names" header using **R**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if df is your dataframe, then you would use:

```
df <- data.frame("names"=rownames(df), df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark, but actually @Roland's is the better (cleaner) answer:  `df$names <- rownames(df)`

Comment: I just tried your answer and since it worked, I ticked marked it. But thanks for your comment on saying this.

Comment: No problem.  They both do the same thing, but @Roland's is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The first "column" is actually not a column, but the row names. You can create a new column using `df$names <- rownames(df)`. Then you might want to change the row names to a simple index: `rownames(df) <- NULL`. Row names are part of the `data.frame` structure; so it is not possible to remove them entirely.